# How do I make a working iif clause in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

So I just learned a Little Bit of SQL in Access in School and i got stuck. The task is to display classes and the date when they „started“ and when they will end. If one of those is empty I have to put the current year in. Here is what i got so far

```
Select
    Klassen.K_Nr,
    Klassen.K_Datumvon,
    K_Datumbis
From
    Klassen
Where
    iif( (K_Datumvon Or K_Datumbis) Is Null, 2018)
```

Comment: SQL is the language, MySQL and Access are both different RDBMS that implement SQL but they have their own dialects. Are you using MySQL or Access? The `IIF` function is only available in Access and Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Im using Access

Comment: If you're using Access, why is your question tagged with MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IIF` function in JET Red SQL (as used by Microsoft Access) has this syntax:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

```
IIf ( expr , truepart , falsepart )
```

In your query you'll want to use `IIF` in the `SELECT` part, not the `WHERE` part as it is not a predicate.

```
SELECT
    K_Nr,
    IIF( K_Datumvon IS NULL, DATE(), K_Datumvon ) AS K_Datumvon,
    IIF( K_Datumbis IS NULL, DATE(), K_Datumbis ) AS K_Datumbis,
FROM
    Klassen
```

Note this SQL uses `DATE()` to return the current date.